# How do I delete all objects and stop all writes to realm database?

Tags: swift, realm

On logout, I am calling

```
let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
    realm.deleteAll()
}
```

on main thread and this works without issue. However, I have some network operations in progress, and writes on background threads be called post-logout. I am now getting

```
RLMException
Adding a deleted or invalidated object to a Realm is not permitted
```

because it is trying to update a deleted object. What is the proper way to resolve this? Do I need to check every object with `object.isValid()` before every write to cover the logout case, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

This may of course be unsuitable for your scenario, but I would suggest that the best way to circumvent such an issue would be to alter the flow of your app such that:-

1. When a user requests logout any background network threads should be halted, or you should wait for them to complete.
2. Once everything is complete, then close and tidy the Realm database.

If you're deleting the database entirely, then cancelling all tasks is probably just as valid as awaiting completion.

If you can't cancel them, then maybe checking whether the user is still logged in on network task completion would help.

Whichever way, I'd suggest that you ensure the 'complete tasks then logout' sequence is followed.